# Prevent application from monitoring file system changes

Tags: windows, winapi, win32-process

I have an old application that monitors file system changes for some unknown reason which causes it to significantly slow down(and I'm thinking it's causing some crashes). There should be no need for the program to do this.

Is there any way to remove or bypass an application's hook that monitors these changes?

IIRC If I create a hook that before(and/or after) the program is run I could simply not call the next hook? I don't mind if this breaks all applications that are running but of course I'd rather just effect this one.

Comment: Programmers never add ReadDirectoryChanges() by accident.  There isn't anything you can do about it if you don't have source code but contact the author or owner for support.

Comment: I'm curious how you came to the conclusion that _There should be no need for the program to do this._ without knowing why it is doing that.

Comment: As I said, this application shouldn't be monitoring changes... why it is doing it is unknown but the application has no need to. Even if it did for some odd ball reason disabling it will not effect the application in any way but increase performance(at least for me).  
if it does break some "feature" in the app I won't shed a tear over it. Also, one doesn't have to have the source code... Hooks are called in a chain and all I have to do is break the chain. There are a few possible ways to do this. I was hoping someone would have done this before and could give me some direction.

Comment: I still don't understand how you come to these conclusions without knowing the details of the implementation, but anyway.  I suppose it depends on what APIs it is using for monitoring.  If it is a standard Win32 API (change notification, shell notification, etc) I suppose you could use something like Detours to hook it.  If there is some kind of driver component it will be more difficult.  Now that I think about it, how do you even know the application is monitoring file system changes if, as you claim, there is no need to?

Comment: Jesus Christ Luke... If you would stop trying to answer why and answer how maybe we would get somewhere. That is, I give a question and you answer it if you can or want and not try to change my question. I shouldn't have to answer how I know this because you are not suppose to assume I'm a retard. Either you know the answer or you don't... if you don't then don't try to change the topic. All your doing is cluttering up the original question with things that have no relevance.

Comment: 1. I know the program is accessing files cause I use process monitor to monitor what the process is doing. 2. It is monitoring all kinds of files that have absolutely no bearing on the application. 3. It does this for some odd ball reason that is not important since the question was simply "How to remove an application hook" and not "Why is this application monitoring files". Either you know how to remove/prevent application hooks or you don't... simple as that(This is almost surely a simple win32 api SetWindowsHook type of thing).

Comment: BTW, here is the function that the program probably uses to monitor the file system changes http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx... That or it might be using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364417%28VS.85%29.aspx.

Comment: Like I said, you can hook it if it is a standard Windows API.  Since you're not even sure what function(s) it is using I'm not sure what more help you expect.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is special API `ReadDirectoryChangesW` that is used to set FS monitoring. You could hook it so that it will do nothing and return success.

Comment: Right, there is no special api which is why it is more complex. I'm not sure simple hooking will work because to prevent the app's hook from being called requires knowing exactly how windows hooks. When I wrote a hook I remember reading that I had to call the next hook or some default procedure or the next one wouldn't be called... but I can't remember exactly or even if that applies in this case.